# Change attributes in nested XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML file with nested elements/nodes. I need to increment the `<proceduralStep>` attribute "id" for each node and its child nodes. My first problem is I haven't been able to make changes to the attribute using  `node.Attributes("id").Value = node.Attributes("id").Value + 1`. It gives an error on the `node.Attributes("id").Value +1`. This is the parent element `/proceduralStep/`. Second problem is I need each nodes attribute to be changed if it's a child element of `<proceduralStep>`. So if it's `/proceduralStep/proceduralStep` that attributes id will be changed to 1.1. I've been searching the net for examples and explanations on how to do this but haven't found any that work.

Sample XML

```
<dmodule>
  <mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStep id="step1">
      <para>Step 1</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step2">
      <figure id="fig2">
        <title>xxxxx</title>
        <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-GAASI"></graphic>
      </figure>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step3">
      <para>Step 3 with link to step 2 (ID 23) here:
                <internalRef internalRefId="step2" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef></para>
      <figure id="fig3">
        <title>xxxxx</title>
        <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-GAASIB0"></graphic>
      </figure>
      <proceduralStep id="step3.1">
        <para>Step 3.2 with link to step 3.1 (ID 23a) here:
                    <internalRef internalRefId="step3.1" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef></para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="step3.2">
        <figure>
          <title>xxxxx</title>
          <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-GAASIB0-00-"></graphic>
        </figure>
        <proceduralStep id="step3.2.1">
          <figure>Step 3.3.1</figure>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep id="step3.2.2">
          <para>Step 3.3.2 with link to step 3.3.1 (ID 23c1) here:
                        <internalRef internalRefId="step3.2.1" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef></para>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep id="step3.2.3">
          <figure>Step 3.3.3</figure>
        </proceduralStep>
      </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
  </mainProcedure>
</dmodule>
```

Not working code

```vb
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim directoryName As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(FILENAME)
        Dim root As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim prefixStep As String = "step"
        Dim prefixFig As String = "fig"
        Dim nameResult As String = Path.GetFileName(FILENAME)
        Dim ns As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()
        Dim mainProcedure As XElement = root.Descendants("mainProcedure").FirstOrDefault()

        RenumberStep(mainProcedure, prefixStep, ns)
        RenumberFigures(mainProcedure, prefixFig, ns)

        For Each internalRef As XElement In doc.Descendants(ns + "internalRef")
        Dim oldId As String = CType(internalRef.Attribute("internalRefId"), String)
            If Not oldId Is Nothing Then
                If dictionary.ContainsKey(oldId) Then
                    internalRef.SetAttributeValue("internalRefId", dictionary(oldId))
                Else
                    '  internalRef.SetAttributeValue("internalRefId", "Error : " & oldId)
                End If
            End If
        Next internalRef

        doc.Save(FILENAME)
Module Module1
    Public dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public dictionaryFig As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Sub RenumberStep(parent As XElement, prefix As String, ns As XNamespace)
        Dim index As Integer = 1
        For Each proceduralStep As XElement In parent.Elements(ns + "proceduralStep")
            Dim oldId = CType(proceduralStep.Attribute("id"), String)
            If Not oldId Is Nothing Then
                dictionary.Add(oldId, prefix + index.ToString())
                proceduralStep.SetAttributeValue("id", prefix + index.ToString())
                RenumberStep(proceduralStep, prefix + index.ToString() + ".", ns)
            Else
                proceduralStep.SetAttributeValue("id", prefix + index.ToString())
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Next proceduralStep
    End Sub

    Sub RenumberFigures(parent As XElement, prefix As String, ns As XNamespace)
        Dim index As Integer = 1

        For Each figure As XElement In parent.Elements(ns + "figure")
            Dim oldfigId = CType(figure.Attribute("id"), String)
            If Not oldfigId Is Nothing Then
                dictionaryFig.Add(oldfigId, prefix + index.ToString())
                figure.SetAttributeValue("id", prefix + index.ToString())
                RenumberFigures(figure, prefix + index.ToString() + ".", ns)
            Else
                figure.SetAttributeValue("id", prefix + index.ToString())
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Next figure
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You don't have any numeric elements; they are all strings. So element = element + 1 will not work on strings. You should isolate the number, increment it, then rebuild the string.

Comment: How would you increment `id="step23c3"` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real simple using a recursive algorithm and xml linq :

```
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Const OUTPUT_FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

    Public dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim root As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim ns As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()
        Dim mainProcedure As XElement = root.Descendants("mainProcedure").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim prefix As String = "step"
        Renumber(mainProcedure, prefix, ns)

        For Each internalRef As XElement In doc.Descendants(ns + "acronymTerm")
            Dim oldId As String = CType(internalRef.Attribute("internalRefId"), String)
            If Not oldId Is Nothing Then

                If dictionary.ContainsKey(oldId) Then
                    internalRef.SetAttributeValue("internalRefId", dictionary(oldId))
                Else
                    internalRef.SetAttributeValue("internalRefId", "Error : " & oldId)
                End If
            End If
        Next internalRef

        doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME)
    End Sub

    Sub Renumber(parent As XElement, prefix As String, ns As XNamespace)
        Dim index As Integer = 1
        For Each proceduralStep As XElement In parent.Elements(ns + "proceduralStep")
            Dim oldId = CType(proceduralStep.Attribute("id"), String)
            dictionary.Add(oldId, prefix + index.ToString())
            proceduralStep.SetAttributeValue("id", prefix + index.ToString())

            Renumber(proceduralStep, prefix + index.ToString() + ".", ns)
            index = index + 1
        Next proceduralStep
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dmodule xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/xml_schema_flat/proced.xsd">
  <mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStep id="step1">
      <para>XX  xxx<acronym id="mosim">XX  xxx<acronymTerm>XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronym>XX  xxx<internalRef internalRefId="Error : Error : fig1" internalRefTargetType="figure" targetTitle="fig1">XX  xxx</internalRef>XX  xxx</para>
      <proceduralStep id="step1.1">
        <para>XX  xxx</para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="step1.2">
        <para>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="mosim">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx</para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="step1.3">
        <para>XX  xxx</para>
      </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step2">
      <para>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="mosim">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<internalRef internalRefId="Error : Error : fig1" internalRefTargetType="figure" targetTitle="fig1">XX  xxx</internalRef>XX  xxx</para>
      <proceduralStep id="step2.1">
        <para>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="mosim">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx</para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="step2.2">
        <para>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="mosim">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx</para>
      </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step3">
      <para>XX  xxx<emphasis>XX  xxx</emphasis>XX  xxx</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step4">
      <para>XX  xxx<emphasis>XX  xxx</emphasis>XX  xxx</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="step5">
      <para>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="lola">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronym id="cd">XX  xxx<acronymTerm>XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronym>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="mosim">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronymTerm internalRefId="cd">XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronym id="dvd">XX  xxx<acronymTerm>XX  xxx</acronymTerm>XX  xxx<acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronymDefinition>XX  xxx</acronym>XX  xxx</para>
    </proceduralStep>
  </mainProcedure>
</dmodule>
```

Comment: thank you for the code. Your example is spot on with what I need except for the 'internalRef' not having the refID changed (it still saids "step23c1"). Your code looks like it's in C would it be possible to get the code back in VB.Net? I'm not familiar with C and get lost in it. Thank you Jen

Comment: I tried putting your code into a C# file but received the following error "There are multiple root elements. Line 4, position 2" Since I don't know C I'm at a loss for what to do. @jdweng

Comment: I changed code to VB.Net and added line to save output.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng

Comment: the internalRefID has the step it was referenced in as the idRefef to goto, but it should be the ID that was referencenced originally. So step3.3.2 has an internalRefId of step3.3.1 and that refID gets pointed to step3.3.1. I know this is not the best explanation. But try to put it simply, each internalRefId has the procedural step id it references. After running the code those internalRefId's now show the procedural step id it is referencing from instead of the internalRefId it's mean to link to.

Comment: I know. It is like the way a two pass compiler works.  The first pass is to get all the variable names and assign the variables to memory location.  Then 2nd pass is to add the memory address to the instructions.  In your case you have to first create a table with the old paragraph numbers and steps they are linked to and renumber the proceduralStep ID.  Then 2nd pass is to renumber the internalRefId using the table of old value and new value.  The two passes are not need if the internalRefId always use a proceduralStep defines earlier in the xml.

Comment: I updated code to add dictionary so old internalRefId get changed properly.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm gonna have to research "dictionary". I thought it would have been put inside a multidimensional array.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code and I'm confused on how it knows to increment the child `<proceduralSteps>` and add the letters to them (Step2a). Know where in the code shows the addition of letters to the step ids.

Comment: Every procedural Step automatically gets incremented starting at 1 and increments sequentially.  It is like writing a new document and starting from scratch.  The code creates a dictionary with the key being the old value before the change and the value being the new value.  The internalRefId you want the paragraph after the renumbering to point to the same paragraph before the change.  So you look up the old value in the dictionary to get the new value.  The assumption are 1) the original xml proceduralSteps are unique 2) internalRefId originally were pointing to valid procedural steps.

Comment: The new code does not use letters, only numbers.  The old code alternated indenting between numbers and letters.  The new method is only using numbers. The numbering method is a style like numbering a word document.  Your description said you only wanted numbers.  You can easily change the code by passing a level number in the parameter list.  A then based on the level use either a number of letter like is done in word documents were each level of indenting uses a different style of paragraph numbering.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this code. I really appreciate it

Comment: for some reason the code does not work with the example I pasted in my original post. I've looked at the document and it's structurally sound. But the proceduralSteps don't get populated. Your assistance is appreciated

Comment: I added code to start at mainProcedure instead of the root.  Also add default namespace.

Comment: Also added check for nothing and changed to look for node acronymTerm

Comment: This worked. Do you think it was because it wasn't at the mainProcedure root? And why check for the acroynmTerm?  Thank you

Comment: Yes.The first prodcuralStep is not under dmodule.   internalRefId is now an attribute of acronymTerm.  Old xml it was an attribute of internalRef

Answer (score 0):

This `node.Attributes("id").Value + 1` won't work because you can't add the number 1 to a string. So how do you increment your id? From what I gather, you need to increment these values

- "step21"
- "step22"
- "step23"
- "step23a"
- "step23b"
- "step23c"
- "step23c1"
- "step23c2"
- "step23c3"

You need to define this. Write a function which takes a string and increments it according to your rules. If you provide the incremented values, we can help with the logic, probably. So add your new increment function,

```vb
Public Function IncrementId(id As String) As String
    Return id & "incremented"
End Function
```

and change your code to call your new increment function,

```vb
node("proceduralStep").SetAttribute("id", IncrementId(node.Attributes("id").Value))
```

and I guess that should do it.

---

However, I prefer Xml serialization over XmlDocument for a few reasons. The biggest reason is that you can model your data with .NET classes and you get strong-typing! For example, [System.Xml.XmlAttribute.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattribute.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlAttribute_Value) is always a string, but sometimes the data in your Xml file is not. In your case it happens to be however.

So here is what I would do. Add these classes which define your data model

```vb
<XmlRoot>
Public Class dmodule
    <XmlElement("proceduralStep")>
    Public Property proceduralSteps As List(Of proceduralStep)
End Class

Partial Public Class proceduralStep
    <XmlElement("proceduralStep")>
    Public Property proceduralSteps As List(Of proceduralStep)
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property id As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property para As para
End Class

Public Class para
    <XmlText>
    Public Property Description As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property internalRef As internalRef
End Class

Public Class internalRef
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property internalRefId As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property internalRefTargetType As String
End Class
```

With these, you can deserialize the xml into strongly-typed .NET objects in memory whose properties can be iterated and modified (instead of passing strings into `doc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/proceduralStep")`)

Now you can deserialize (file >> memory) and serialize (memory >> file).

```vb
Dim myDmodule As dmodule
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(dmodule))

' read to memory
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Test\34 XML Parsing\XML File\CascadingStepsExample.xml")
    myDmodule = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), dmodule)
End Using

' write to file
Using sw As New StreamWriter("C:\Test\34 XML Parsing\XML File\CascadingStepsExample_inc.xml")
    serializer.Serialize(sw, myDmodule)
End Using
```

You can add some functions to recursively find all id attributes and increment them

```vb
' increment function
Public Shared Function incrementId(id As String) As String
    Return id & "incremented" ' how do you REALLY increment this?
End Function
' recursive id finder and incrementer method
Public Shared Sub incrementIds(steps As IEnumerable(Of proceduralStep))
    For Each s In steps
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.id) Then
            s.id = incrementId(s.id)
        End If
        incrementIds(s.proceduralSteps)
    Next
End Sub
```

Just call the function after you have deserialized to your model and serialize back to the file.

```vb
Dim myDmodule As dmodule
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(dmodule))

Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Test\34 XML Parsing\XML File\CascadingStepsExample.xml")
    myDmodule = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), dmodule)
End Using

' increment recursively
incrementIds(myDmodule.proceduralSteps)

Using sw As New StreamWriter("C:\Test\34 XML Parsing\XML File\CascadingStepsExample_inc.xml")
    serializer.Serialize(sw, myDmodule)
End Using
```

Still, we're missing the increment logic, so you need to come up with it, and again, we can help with that.

Comment: XmlSerializer is really confusing to me. thank you for responding I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: @JenPann familiarize yourself with [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/). It is just a way to move data between .NET classes and files or streams, and Xml Serialization is as subset of it. XmlSerialization is built into .NET Framework and it makes working with Xml files a lot easier.

Comment: I'll read up on Serialization. Thank you for the suggestion @djv

Answer (score 0):

So here is a guess since there isn't a clearly defined 'increment'.  Used literal for testing.

```
    Dim strXMLPath As String = "C:\Test\34 XML Parsing\XML File\CascadingStepsExample.xml"

    Dim doc As XElement
    ' doc = XElement.Load(strXMLPath)

    'for texting
    doc = <dmodule>
              <proceduralStep id="step21">
                  <para>Step 1</para>
              </proceduralStep>
              <proceduralStep id="step22">
                  <para>Step 2</para>
              </proceduralStep>
              <proceduralStep id="step23">
                  <para>Step 3 with link to step 2 (ID 23) here:
  <internalRef internalRefId="step23" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef>
                  </para>
                  <proceduralStep id="step23a">
                      <para>Step 3.1</para>
                  </proceduralStep>
                  <proceduralStep id="step23b">
                      <para>Step 3.2 with link to step 3.1 (ID 23a) here:
    <internalRef internalRefId="step23a" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef>
                      </para>
                  </proceduralStep>
                  <proceduralStep id="step23c">
                      <para>Step 3.3</para>
                      <proceduralStep id="step23c1">
                          <para>Step 3.3.1</para>
                      </proceduralStep>
                      <proceduralStep id="step23c2">
                          <para>Step 3.3.2 with link to step 3.3.1 (ID 23c1) here:
      <internalRef internalRefId="step23c1" internalRefTargetType="step"></internalRef>
                          </para>
                      </proceduralStep>
                      <proceduralStep id="step23c3">
                          <para>Step 3.3.3</para>
                      </proceduralStep>
                      <!-- end of step 3.3.3-->
                  </proceduralStep>
                  <!--end of step 3.3-->
              </proceduralStep>
              <!--end of step 3-->
          </dmodule>

    For Each el As XElement In doc...<proceduralStep>
        'increment logic GUESS
        Dim prfx As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim num As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim sufx As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim id As New System.Text.StringBuilder(el.@id)
        Dim inNum As Boolean = False
        Dim inSuf As Boolean = False
        For x As Integer = 0 To id.Length - 1
            Dim n As Boolean = False
            If Integer.TryParse(id(x), Nothing) Then
                n = True
            End If
            Select Case True
                Case inSuf
                    sufx.Append(id(x))
                Case inNum AndAlso n
                    num.Append(id(x))
                Case inNum
                    inSuf = True
                    sufx.Append(id(x))
                Case n
                    inNum = True
                    num.Append(id(x))
                Case Else
                    prfx.Append(id(x))
            End Select
        Next
        If num.Length > 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer = Integer.Parse(num.ToString)
            i += 1
            el.@id = prfx.ToString & i.ToString & sufx.ToString
        End If
    Next
```